# How to add picture to pdf file using PDFClown

Tags: java, eofexception, pdfclown

I use PDFClown .jar library in order to convert jpeg images to pdf files. However, I get the below error:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException*

Here you can find the code:

```
org.pdfclown.documents.contents.entities.Image image = 
org.pdfclown.documents.contents.entities.Image.get("c:" + java.io.File.separator + "bg.jpg");
org.pdfclown.documents.contents.xObjects.XObject imageXObject = image.toXObject(document);
composer.showXObject(imageXObject);                 
composer.flush();       
document.getFile().save("c:\\test.pdf" , SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
```

Please let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce your issue:

```
public void testAddPicture() throws IOException
{
    org.pdfclown.files.File file = new org.pdfclown.files.File();

    Page page = new Page(file.getDocument());
    file.getDocument().getPages().add(page);
    PrimitiveComposer primitiveComposer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);

    Image image = Image.get("src\\test\\resources\\mkl\\testarea\\pdfclown0\\content\\Willi-1.jpg");
    XObject imageXObject = image.toXObject(file.getDocument());
    primitiveComposer.showXObject(imageXObject, new Point2D.Double(100,100), new Dimension(300, 300));                 

    primitiveComposer.flush();

    file.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "PdfWithImage.pdf"), SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
    file.close();
}
```

*([ShowImage.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfclown0/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfclown0/content/ShowImage.java))*

I get no `EOFException`, instead the result looks as expected:

[image: Screenshot of resulting PDF with image]

Thus, the issue seems to be related to your JPG file, its content probably is broken or beyond PdfClown's JPG support, or it may be a file system permissions related issue.